# Iterating a floating point range in C++

Tags: c++, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I would like to iterate over a range of floating point numbers, such as in the following example.

```
for (double d = 1.0; d <= 2.0; d += 0.1)
{
   cout << d << endl;
}
```

Because it is impossible to represent 0.1 accurately, the last value of 2.0 is not printed.

How can I ensure that the last value in this case and similar cases is not omitted?

Comment: Never use floating point in loops, or instead compare for the exact value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286394/for-loop-in-c-using-double-breaking-out-one-step-early-boundary-value-not-rea

Comment: @GI Joe: Common numerical methods like Newton-Raphson do exactly that. But they of course aren't aiming for exact values, because it's indeed the root cause of problems like this one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Loop over integers, and divide by a floating point number:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
  std::cout << std::setprecision(1) << std::fixed;

  for (int d = 10; d <= 20; ++d)
  {
     std::cout << d/10. << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
1.0
1.1
1.2
1.3
1.4
1.5
1.6
1.7
1.8
1.9
2.0
```

Comment: This is very heavy on int/float conversion. It would be faster/better to use a loop control value and update a floating point value independently.

Comment: @Apriori If it matters, and if you can show that it makes a difference, then *maybe*.

Comment: @Apriori: That would be less accurate, because the error in representing `0.1` would accumulate across all iterations of the loop.

Comment: @dan04, yes that's true. It depends on if you're going for speed or precision, and how long you let the errors accumulate. Still I don't think it's good practice to have lots of avoidable int-to-float conversions. Thinking about it more now, I suppose if you want to get rid of the round-off error you could increment a copy of d as a float, the floating point representation of whole numbers this small will not suffer round off error, and then divide by floating point ten. Alternatively, an int to float look-up table can be used. As a matter of fact this loop could be unrolled/hard-coded.

Comment: @juanchopanza The loop in question is certainly handled. In the general case though, how do you plan to obtain the `int` range? Does, by any chance, involve floating point multiplication and then truncation to `int` and if so how wouldn't that suffer from the same problems the loop in question suffers? eg `11.23 * 100 = 1122.99999` and then `1122` (PS It was a dummy example, it works fine on those numbers. Maybe you plan to use `ceil`/`floor`, maybe there's an exception when multiplying with powers of ten, I don't know, I just want to sort this out)

Answer (score 4):

Due to floating point numbers not being accurate in such kind of situations I usually work around by "emulating" them through integers. At least for simple cases like this one.

```
for (int i = 10; i <= 20; ++i)
{
   cout << i / 10.0 << endl;
}
```

That should give you the closest you can get with floating points for any of the values.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using fixed increments (like in your example), one way is to use integers:

```
for (int i = 10; i != 20; ++i)
{
   cout << (i / 10.0) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to use and update an integer value to control your loop. And a use and update a floating point value to use to output. I'm assuming your real-world case is a little more complex than this.

This will execute the loop the correct number of times and save on int to float conversions. The double value will be accurate so long as you don't loop too many times or let it get too big, then you will start getting rounding errors. In general you can come up with ways to correct for this, but with a loop of size/range it's a non-issue.

```
double d = 1.0;
for (unsigned i = 0; i <= 10; ++i, d += 0.1)
{
   cout << d << endl;
}
```

If you want to avoid cumulative round-off error from adding 0.1, it can be done like this:

```
double d = 10.0;
for (unsigned i = 0; i <= 10; ++i, d += 1.0)
{
   cout << (d / 10.0) << endl;
}
```

This is more accurate because small whole numbers can be represented accurately in a floating point format. However it costs a floating point division, but still avoids the int-to-float conversions.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (double d = 1.0; d <= 2.02; d += 0.1)
{
   cout << d << endl;
}
```

Comparing double to be equal is hard work, but slight increase it will do the trick.