# Why does a for loop terminate early when iterating through a double?

Tags: c++, for-loop, double, iteration

If a for loop "iterates" a double from 0.00 to 0.40, for example, even when writing `<=`, the loop terminates when `i=39`. When performing essentially the same thing using integers, the program acts normally.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    for (double i = 0.00; i <= 0.40; i += 0.01) {
        cout << i << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This returns `1 2 3` ... `37 38 39`.

You can test this here: https://ideone.com/bP3ilk

What causes this behavior and is there an ideal way to fix this, as just writing `i <= 0.41` seems like a hacky solution. Even more so if the 0.40 was a user entered value, adding a small quantity certainly be considered bad practice.

Sorry if the title and question are poorly phrases, I'm not sure how to word this.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Not sure how I didn't think of that. Marked as duplicate. Thanks.

Comment: here is another similar question asked on here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286394/for-loop-in-c-using-double-breaking-out-one-step-early-boundary-value-not-rea hope that helps